# "We're Sorry, Client not found" FreeIPA, Keycloak setup

Tags: python, django, keycloak, freeipa

I am setting up FreeIPA and Keycloak for user authentication for a django webapp. I have set up the client id and client secret in the .bashrc file and have included my path properly in django (the website loads, just not properly).

The error displayed is "We're sorry, Client not found." I figure this may have something to do with setup.
[image: error message]

What should I do to fix this and make the ipa/keycloak login show the login fields?

Comment: You need to add and configure client in the keycloak properly - https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#_clients

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my answer by looking at the settings from this post: [mozilla-django-oidc with keycloak on django 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67287849/mozilla-django-oidc-with-keycloak-on-django-3)

These were the two lines I needed to add in my settings.py:

```
OIDC_RP_CLIENT_ID = 'my_client_id'
OIDC_RP_CLIENT_SECRET = os.environ.get("my_client_secret")
```